# visually duplicating existing record when deleted/updated record

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

does anyone here encountered when you are updating a data it duplicates the existing data visually only but when I will back and go to the activity again it shows the real data.
Data 1 and Data 2, when I delete Data 2, it will show Data 1 Data2 and Data 1. However like I said, it is just visual had to go back and go to the activity again to show the current data which is Data 1 only since Data 2 has been deleted. I have tried searching but none of them are related to my problem and I genuinely do not know if this is from the database or the card or in the recyclerview. Any help will be much appreciated.

MainActivity

```
public class AdminReqFormsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView adminreqform_recycler;
    ImageView adminreqfromfield_backbtn;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ArrayList<ResearchReqForm> reqFormArrayList;
    AdminRequestFormAdapter adminRequestFormAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_req_forms);
        adminreqform_recycler = findViewById(R.id.adminreqform_recycler);
        adminreqfromfield_backbtn = findViewById(R.id.adminreqfromfield_backbtn);


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ResearchRequest");
        adminreqform_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        reqFormArrayList = new ArrayList<ResearchReqForm>();
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    ResearchReqForm researchReqForm = dataSnapshot.getValue(ResearchReqForm.class);
                    reqFormArrayList.add(researchReqForm);
                }
                adminRequestFormAdapter = new AdminRequestFormAdapter(AdminReqFormsActivity.this, reqFormArrayList);
                adminreqform_recycler.setAdapter(adminRequestFormAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(AdminReqFormsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        adminreqfromfield_backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeAdminActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class ResearchReqForm {
    String studentName;
    String requestedtitle;
    String requestedtags;
    String requestMessage;
    String requestid;
    String requestStatus;

    public ResearchReqForm() {
    }

    public ResearchReqForm(String studentName, String requestedtitle, String requestedtags, String requestMessage, String requestid, String requestStatus) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.requestedtitle = requestedtitle;
        this.requestedtags = requestedtags;
        this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
        this.requestid = requestid;
        this.requestStatus = requestStatus;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }

    public String getRequestedtitle() {
        return requestedtitle;
    }

    public void setRequestedtitle(String requestedtitle) {
        this.requestedtitle = requestedtitle;
    }

    public String getRequestedtags() {
        return requestedtags;
    }

    public void setRequestedtags(String requestedtags) {
        this.requestedtags = requestedtags;
    }

    public String getRequestMessage() {
        return requestMessage;
    }

    public void setRequestMessage(String requestMessage) {
        this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
    }

    public String getRequestid() {
        return requestid;
    }

    public void setRequestid(String requestid) {
        this.requestid = requestid;
    }

    public String getRequestStatus() {
        return requestStatus;
    }

    public void setRequestStatus(String requestStatus) {
        this.requestStatus = requestStatus;
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class AdminRequestFormAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdminRequestFormAdapter.AdminRequestFormViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ResearchReqForm> requestFormArrayList;

    public AdminRequestFormAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ResearchReqForm> reqFormsList){
        context = c;
        requestFormArrayList = reqFormsList;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdminRequestFormViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new AdminRequestFormAdapter.AdminRequestFormViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.admin_request_list,parent,false));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdminRequestFormViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.adminsudentname_reqcv.setText(requestFormArrayList.get(position).getStudentName());
        holder.adminrelatedtopic_requestcv.setText(requestFormArrayList.get(position).getRequestedtitle());
        holder.admintopictags_requestcv.setText(requestFormArrayList.get(position).getRequestedtags());
        holder.adminbriefmessage_reqeuestcv.setText(requestFormArrayList.get(position).getRequestMessage());
        holder.deleteresearch_request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alert.setTitle("Delete Request Research?");
                alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?");

                alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ResearchRequest");
                        final String uniqueKey = requestFormArrayList.get(position).getRequestid();
                        databaseReference.child(uniqueKey).removeValue();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Student's Request has been deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Form Closed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
            }
        });
        holder.acceptresearch_request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Test Toast For Accept", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return requestFormArrayList.size();
    }

    class AdminRequestFormViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView adminsudentname_reqcv, adminrelatedtopic_requestcv, admintopictags_requestcv, adminbriefmessage_reqeuestcv;
        Button deleteresearch_request, acceptresearch_request;
        public AdminRequestFormViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            adminsudentname_reqcv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adminsudentname_reqcv);
            adminrelatedtopic_requestcv =itemView.findViewById(R.id.adminrelatedtopic_requestcv);
            admintopictags_requestcv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.admintopictags_requestcv);
            adminbriefmessage_reqeuestcv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adminbriefmessage_reqeuestcv);

            deleteresearch_request = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteresearch_request);
            acceptresearch_request = itemView.findViewById(R.id.acceptresearch_request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - there's a lot of code there and it may be hard for others to know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is actually quite common and comes from a misunderstanding of how Firebase snapshots work.

Whenever your `onDataChange` is called it gets a full snapshot of all the data at `databaseReference`. So even if there's only one change since you rendered the data, you get called with a full snapshot of all data at `databaseReference` including the change. And since you add all data in `snapshot` to `reqFormArrayList`, you end up duplicating it each time `onDataChange` gets called.

The simplest solution is to clear `reqFormArrayList` inside `onDataChange`:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        reqFormArrayList.clear(); // this is the new line
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            ResearchReqForm researchReqForm = dataSnapshot.getValue(ResearchReqForm.class);
            reqFormArrayList.add(researchReqForm);
        }
        adminRequestFormAdapter = new AdminRequestFormAdapter(AdminReqFormsActivity.this, reqFormArrayList);
        adminreqform_recycler.setAdapter(adminRequestFormAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(AdminReqFormsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
})
```